# Primefaces how to erase validation fails in dialog when reopen the dialog

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a required input field in a `p:dialog`. If firstly I submit nothing for the field, a validation error happens on that field. Then I close the dialog and reopen it, the validation error still exists. What can I do to eliminate the validation error when close the dialog?

Answer (score 12):

You should use the `p:resetInput` on the element that you have to open the dialog.

For example if you use a `p:commandButton`

```
<p:commandButton value="Open dialog" update=":dialogId" oncomplete="PF('dialogWidget').show()" >
    <p:resetInput target=":dialogId" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This will reset the cached values (including the validation messages) upon opening the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce your case and you could do the following:

- Make your dialog `closable="false"`.
- Add a `Cancel` button that will hide the dialog.
- Add a [resetInput](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/resetInput.jsf) component from Primefaces Extensions inside your Cancel button. This will clear the form validations and values.

Here is an example that assumes your dialog as a `widgetVar` named `wvDialog`.

```
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="wvDialog.hide()">
        <pe:resetInput for="myDialogFormId />
    </p:commandButton>
```

You could even call a bean method in the button `actionListener` if you need.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Button I really want a close button on the top right corner......

Comment: I have a *Cancel* button on my page with `oncomplete='PF("wvDialog").hide();'`. But still when I open the dialog it shows error messages there.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `p:dialog` or `p:message` every time you submit the Form.
You can do that by using **update** attribute of `p:commandButton`.

```
<p:commandButton update="ID_OF_DIALOG" />
```